# CSS Expand grid item to left or right when space freed up

Tags: css, angular, css-grid

I have the following template with a grid template and some buttons that hide and show `div1` and `div4`, and the area of `div2` and `div3` should expand accordingly. I want that when `div1` is not present, that `div2` and `div3` area should expand to the left (start from `column 1` instead of `column 2`), and similarly `div3` should end at `column 6` when `div4` is not present.

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  height: 500px;
}

.parent div {
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 6 / 2;
}

.div2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 6;
}

.div2.expandedLeft {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 6;
}

.div3 {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 6 / 5;
}

.div3.expandedLeft {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 6 / 5;
}

.div3.expandedRight {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 6 / 6;
}

.div3.expandedLeft.expandedRight {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 6 / 6;
}

.div4 {
  grid-area: 2 / 5 / 6 / 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div1" *ngIf="!hideDiv1"></div>
  <div class="div2" [class.expandedLeft]="hideDiv1"></div>
  <div class="div3" [class.expandedLeft]="hideDiv1" [class.expandedRight]="hideDiv2"></div>
  <div class="div4" *ngIf="!hideDiv2"></div>
</div>

<div>
  <button (click)="hideDiv1 = true">hide it</button>
  <button (click)="hideDiv1 = false">show it</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button (click)="hideDiv2 = true">hide it</button>
  <button (click)="hideDiv2 = false">show it</button>
</div>
```

As you can see what I have tried was to add some classes when `div1` or `div4` are removed from DOM, and I play with the `grid-area`. It works. But I am wondering if there is a more automatic way of doing it?

Here is a stackblitz that shows my working solution https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rp5xkh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a series of selectors this is actually possible but I'd suggest it's not really scalable.

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  height: 20vh;
  margin-bottom: 2vh;
}

.parent div {
  border: 1px black solid;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 8vh;
}

.div1 {
  grid-row: 1 / 6;
  grid-column: 1;
  background: lightblue;
}

.div2 {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.div1+.div2 {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 2 / -1;
}

.div3 {
  grid-row: 2 / 6;
  grid-column: 1 / 5;
  background: red;
}

.div1~.div3 {
  grid-row: 2 / 6;
  grid-column: 2 / 5;
}

.div3:last-child {
  grid-row: 2 / 6;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.div1~.div3:last-child {
  grid-row: 2 / 6;
  grid-column: 2 / -1;
}

.div4 {
  grid-row: 2 / 6;
  grid-column: 5 /6;
  background: orange;
  opacity: .5
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div1">1</div>
  <div class="div2">2</div>
  <div class="div3">3</div>
  <div class="div4">4</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="div2">2</div>
  <div class="div3">3</div>
  <div class="div4">4</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="div1">1</div>
  <div class="div2">2</div>
  <div class="div3">3</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="div2">2</div>
  <div class="div3">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sorry for the newbie question but what does it mean to have a negative column end like in `grid-column: 2 / -1;` ?

Comment: And can you also tell me the need of having a `display:flex` for the children?

Comment: the `-1` just means the last column. I just added the flex to align the text in the divs...its not necessary